# Change UISearchDisplayController appearance

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uitableview, ios5, uikit

I've added an `UISearchDisplayController` to my iPad app, which is managing a `UITableView` (like this is what its supposed to do). However I think that the `UISearchDisplayController`  is coloring the table cells with a dark grey color, when the search is inactive (e.g. the searchbar text is nil), like so:

[image: UISearchDisplayController]

Is there a way I can make the tableview look like normal (white cells), even when the search bar is empty?

Answer (score 1):

you have to config the SearchResultsTableView in searchDisplayController:didLoadSearchResultsTableView

for example:

```
-(void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller didLoadSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
    tableView.rowHeight = 50.0f;
}
```

make sure you have set the delegates of searchDisplayController

Comment: I'm afraid this didnt help. The message `didLoadSearchResultsTableView` is sent when the result table is populated, but NOT when the search is not yet started, and the view is empty. E.g. in the above screenshot, when the dark grey table view is visible, `didLoadSearchResultsTableView` was NOT fired. Once I enter a word in the search box, the table view turns white, and `didLoadSearchResultsTableView` is fired.

Comment: try -(void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller willShowSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView or some of this delegates